# Review of String to Long bijection class - focus on readability/maintainabiliy

Tags: java

I wrote the following interface and class to bijectively map a string to a long. I would like feedback on how to make the code more readable and maintainable.

**Interface:**

```
/**
 * Bijectively maps a string consisting of chars from a predefined 'charSet' to a long value
 * Bijective mapping ensures that the conversions are collision-less
 * 
 * @invariant: All mappings are bijective.
 * @invariant: Defined for all string permutations <= getMaxStringLength()
 * @invariant: Defined for all longs in range [getMinLongValue(), getMaxLongValue()]
 */
public interface StringAndLongConverter {
  public char[]  getMappedChars();                      /* O(n) */
  public long    getMinLongValue();                     /* O(1) */
  public long    getMaxLongValue();                     /* O(1) */
  public int     getMaxStringLength();                  /* O(1) */
  public boolean isValidLong(final long n);             /* O(1) */
  public boolean isValidString(final String str);       /* O(n) */
  public String  convertLongToString(final long n);     /* O(n) */
  public long    convertStringToLong(final String str); /* O(n) */
}
```

**Concrete Class:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
 * @author awashburn
 * 1. Use base conversion principals to bijectively map
 *    a string to a long for a pre-defined character set.
 *
 * 2. Treat the characters as digits 
 *    and the cardinality of the character set as the base
 *
 * 3. Use an imaginary empty character to mark string termination.
 */
public class ConcreteStringAndLongConveter implements StringAndLongConverter {

  private final char[]  CHAR_MAP;
  private final HashMap<Character,Integer> CHAR_HASHMAP;
  private final int     NUM_MAPPED_CHARS;
  private final int     MAX_STR_LEN;
  private final long    MIN_VALUE;
  private final long    MAX_VALUE;
  private final Pattern REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR;

  public ConcreteStringAndLongConveter(char[] charSet) {
    if(charSet == null  )
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot Pass in null reference");
    if(charSet.length==0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot Pass in empty set"     );

    /* Don't re-arrange, order-dependent initializations */
    CHAR_MAP             = removeDuplicateCharacters(charSet);
    CHAR_HASHMAP         = generateHashMap();
    NUM_MAPPED_CHARS     = CHAR_MAP.length+1; // accounts for imaginary empty character
    MAX_STR_LEN          = calcMaxPossibleChars();
    MIN_VALUE            = calcLongMinVal();
    MAX_VALUE            = calcLongMaxVal();
    REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR = createRegExValidator();
  }

  /* --<[ Dynamic Initialization Calculation Methods ]>-- */

  private final char[] removeDuplicateCharacters(char[] charArr) {
    char[] tmp = new char[charArr.length];
    Arrays.sort(charArr);
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<charArr.length-1; ++i)
      if(charArr[i]!=charArr[i+1])
        tmp[index++] = charArr[i];
    tmp[index++] = charArr[charArr.length-1];
    return Arrays.copyOf(tmp,index);
  } 

  private final HashMap<Character,Integer> generateHashMap() {
    HashMap<Character,Integer> mapping = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<CHAR_MAP.length; ++i)
      mapping.put(CHAR_MAP[i], i+1);
    return mapping;
  }

  private final int calcMaxPossibleChars() {
    return (int)(Math.floor(Math.log(Long.MAX_VALUE) / Math.log(NUM_MAPPED_CHARS)));
  }

  private final long calcLongMinVal() {
    return 0L;
  }

  private final long calcLongMaxVal(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_STR_LEN; ++i)
      sb.append(CHAR_MAP[CHAR_MAP.length-1]);
    return encodeStrToLong(sb.toString());
  }

  /* Dynamically create RegEx validation string for invalid characters */
  private final Pattern createRegExValidator() {
    return Pattern.compile("^["+Pattern.quote(new String(CHAR_MAP))+"]+?$");
  }

  /* --<[ Interface Implmentation Methods ]>-- */

  @Override
  public  final char[] getMappedChars() { 
    return Arrays.copyOf(CHAR_MAP,CHAR_MAP.length);
  }

  @Override
  public final int getMaxStringLength() {
    return MAX_STR_LEN;
  }

  @Override
  public final long getMaxLongValue() {
    return MAX_VALUE;
  }

  @Override
  public final long getMinLongValue() {
    return MIN_VALUE;
  }

  @Override
  public  final boolean isValidString(final String str) {
    return str != null && !str.equals("")           //not null or empty String
    && str.length() <= MAX_STR_LEN                  //not too long
    && REGEX_CHAR_VALIDATOR.matcher(str).matches(); //and only valid chars in string
  }

  @Override
  public  final boolean isValidLong(final long n) {
    return MIN_VALUE <= n && n <= MAX_VALUE;
  }

  @Override
  public  final String  convertLongToString(final long n) {
    if(!isValidLong(n))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Long: "+Long.toHexString(n));
    return encodeLongToStr(n);
  }

  @Override
  public  final long    convertStringToLong(final String str) {
    if(!isValidString(str))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid String: "+str);
    return encodeStrToLong(str);
  }

  /* --<[ Internal Helper Methods ]>-- */

  /* Assumes a validated Long was passed in */
  private final String encodeLongToStr(long index) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(; index!=0; index/=NUM_MAPPED_CHARS)
      sb.append(CHAR_MAP[(int)(index%NUM_MAPPED_CHARS)-1]); // -1 accounts for empty char
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /* Assumes a validated String was passed in */
  private final long encodeStrToLong(String str) {
    long output = 0L;
    for(int i=str.length()-1; i >=0; --i) {
      output += CHAR_HASHMAP.get(str.charAt(i));
      if(i!=0)
        output *= NUM_MAPPED_CHARS;
    }
    return output;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The interface**

- Always try to keep methods on an interface to a minimum.Try to focus on what a client really needs.

In you case this should suffice :

```
public interface StringAndLongConverter {
  public boolean isValidLong(final long n);
  public boolean isValidString(final String str);
  public String  convertLongToString(final long n);
  public long    convertStringToLong(final String str);
}
```

- You list the order of complexity in the interface definition, but they are actually properties of the implementation. A different implementation may have different complexities.

**The implementation class**

- my IDE immediately points out that your private methods are marked `final`. While not wrong, it is superfluous.
- fields that are non `static` or non `final` are usually named using [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).
- drop the methods that I've dropped on the interface.
- You use `for` and `if` without braces. Again, not wrong, but I find braces to be clearer. Especially when nesting.
- The name of the implementation class has a typo.
- Since you sort the characters (when eliminating duplicates), you could do the conversion of a character to a number without a HashMap, and just use binary search. This would still be very fast, but would use a lot less memory. (just an idea)
- replace `calcLongMinVal()` by a constant.
- encoding and decoding can also be done with bit manipulation With some clever naming it could even be more readable, it would not give the same mapping, but would avoid repeated divisions when converting long to String. (just an idea)

Comment: The repeated division was chosen rather then bit-twiddling to give a compact and continuous mapping of `long`s in the range. The bit-twiddling approach may produce a non-continuous range of of values, ie there may exist a `long n` such that `MIN_VALUE <= n && n<= MAX_VALUE && convertLongToString(n)` will throw an exception. [I tried the bit-twiddling before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14541792/1465011).

Comment: This would only matter if you want to decode `long`s that aren'ty the result of being encoded by the converter. I can't see the use of that, but if you want that, you can stick to divisions.

Comment: You are correct, but that is a feature that I want. Bit-twiddling is probably preferable if that feature isn't desired.

Comment: On closer inspection, this property also does not hold for repeated division; given alphabet `{'a', 'b'}` the converter will fail for `3L`.

Comment: I should make a test suite to ensure this desired property exists. Thanks for pointing that out.